# Heroku build successfull, but application error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy an app which has a node backend and a react front end. I am using heroku and my code is below. It says there is an error with mongo, I tried re installing my node modules. I dont have much experience with heroku so any input would be great. Thanks in advance.
In server.js -

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

In package.json -

```
{
  "author": "Spotify",
  "name": "web-api-auth-examples",
  "description": "Basic examples of the Spotify authorization flows through OAuth 2",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "querystring": "~0.2.0",
    "request": "~2.83.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "validator": "^10.4.0"
  }
}
```

The heroku log -

```
2018-08-18T03:08:30.415893+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-08-18T03:08:30.415896+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-08-18T03:08:30.415899+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! web-api-auth-examples@0.0.2 start: `node server.js                    `
2018-08-18T03:08:30.415909+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the web-api-auth-examples@0.0.2 start sc                    ript.
2018-08-18T03:08:30.415905+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-08-18T03:08:30.423862+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-08-18T03:08:30.423859+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-18T03:08:30.415901+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-08-18T03:08:30.415913+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is                     likely additional logging output above.
2018-08-18T03:08:30.423864+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-08-18T03_08_30_416Z-debug                    .log
2018-08-18T03:08:30.536987+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-08-18T03:08:30.539851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-08-18T03:08:30.502667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-08-18T03:08:42.074442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-08-18T03:08:45.349152+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-18T03:08:45.349173+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-08-18T03:08:45.349171+00:00 app[web.1]: > web-api-auth-examples@0.0.2 start /app
2018-08-18T03:08:45.349174+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-18T03:08:46.080144+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:549
2018-08-18T03:08:46.080165+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-08-18T03:08:46.080167+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-08-18T03:08:46.080168+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-18T03:08:46.080171+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
2018-08-18T03:08:46.080172+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
2018-08-18T03:08:46.080174+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
```

Comment: You need to install mongoose npm install -s mongoose

Comment: its interesting that it worked on your machine, meanwhile `mongoose` isn't listed on your `package.json`

Comment: Yeah I think it was because it was downloaded on my machine but wasn't listed in package.json so heroku didn't know to install it. @EdwinHarly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand From your error and given package.json is that you are using mongoose somewhere in your application but mongoose is actually not installed.

Install mongoose to resolve the issue

```
npm install -s mongoose
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the application error. It was odd because it worked when I ran it locally, im guessing that was because mongoose was on my machine but heroku didnt know to install it. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: Cheers:) Kindly upvote and accept if it resolves your issue.